# Drop levels of the same name from the whole dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Dropping a level in a single factor in a dataframe is easy, and base R and various packages offer several ways to do this. But is there a way to drop levels with the same name from several factors across the dataframe?

For example, in dataframe `DF`, is there a way to drop the level `D` from both `V1` and `V2`?

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "E")),
                 V2=factor(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "E")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example to drop a specific factor level from all factors in a dataframe.

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "E")),
                 V2=factor(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "E")))

dropLevels <- function(col, value){
     if(is.factor(col)){
          droplevels(col, value)
     }else{col}
}


DF %>% purrr::modify(~ dropLevels(., "D"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapply` and `droplevels`, however, you'll need to factor the variables again.

```
mapply(DF, FUN = function(x) droplevels(x, "D")) 

     V1  V2 
[1,] "A" "A"
[2,] "B" "A"
[3,] "C" "A"
[4,] "A" "A"
[5,] NA  NA 
[6,] "E" "E"
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, but I think @TBT8's answer is more straightforward.

Comment: Thank you and glad I could help. @TVT8's answer is indeed somewhat more straightforward. I also gave him a vote up :)